# What did Sex Machine turn into?

Tags: vampire, from-dusk-till-dawn

In "From Dusk till Dawn" two bank robbers and a family on vacation go to Mexico, enter a bar and fight a legion of vampires. There are a few others who fight the vampires, one of whom goes by the name Sex Machine. He eventually turns into a vampire but is beheaded, then transforms into a strange creature.

**What does he turn into after his decapitation?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/from_dusk_till_dawk.html) indicates that he turned into a "*half bat, half devil vamp*":

> Seth tries to get to the front door, when Sex Machine, now a half bat,
>   half devil vamp, about six foot seven, drops from above in front of
>   him. Seth RAMS the stake in its chest. The Sex Machine-thing screams
>   out, LIFTING the hammer and Seth off the ground.

[image]

Comment: Thats sad i was hoping they were referencing the ancient myth that once you kill a vampire you must chop of its head and burn it or it will turn into a werewolf

Comment: @giacomocasanova Huh? Are you serious? Never heard of that. Is that referenced somewhere?